# minimuize ring volume at certain times of day

Tags: applications, automation, ringtone, volume

I have an android phone, a kid, and some friends who call just after the kid goes to bed. My friends will call, at 7pm, my phone will ring, and the ring will wake up my kid. Is there an app that can minimize my ringer volume based on time of day? I want my phone to ring, but I don't want to have to remember to turn the volume down every day.

Comment: Have you checked whether your device supports profiles for that? Some devices/ROMs do. If not, check our [automation](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/automation/info) tag – or take a look at [my list of automation apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_automation).

Comment: @j0h: Please edit your question

Answer (score 0):

Sound & notification > Do not disturb. You can set specific time intervals